# Trouble with updgrading distributions due to dependency issue (libdrm-amdgpu1 won't upgrade))

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dependencies, do-release-upgrade

I've tried to follow the guidance I get on this forum but am a little lost. I tried running `sudo do-release-upgrade` and got

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

Then `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` gives

```
Fetched 88,7 kB in 3s (27,5 kB/s)                     
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Then `apt list --upgradable` gives

```
Listing... Done
libdrm-amdgpu1/focal 2.4.107-1029 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4.101-2~18.04.1]
N: There are 27 additional versions. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.
```

I have a Dell Precision without a NVIDIA graphics card, just the on-chip Intel graphics. I attempted to install the software DaVinci Resolve, after which my computer started to randomly shut off and overheat. So I removed it but maybe have some GPU-related dependencies still installed? I was pretty agressive about uninstalling. (I also accidentally removed some packages like System Info, Settings, and so forth when trying to remove all traces of DaVinci Resolve...)

Then `sudo apt-get upgrade libdrm-amdgpu1` gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdrm-amdgpu1 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.28) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.5 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I also saw some advice to run `apt list --installed | grep -v bionic` which I think lists the software I installed that doesn't have a release for my current version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (beaver-osp1-varys X34)).

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Listing...
canonical-oem-keyring/now 2009.07.23+build3 all [installed,local]
cnijfilter2/now 6.30-1+1804 amd64 [installed,local]
davmail/now 6.0.1-3390-1 all [installed,local]
dell-recovery/now 1.61~somerville5 all [installed,local]
dell-recovery-casper/now 1.61~somerville5 all [installed,local]
dell-service-meta/unknown,unknown,now 7ubuntu3 all [installed]
dell-super-key/now 0.04 all [installed,local]
ferdi/now 5.5.0-2116 amd64 [installed,local]
franz/now 5.6.1-1830 amd64 [installed,local]
libdrm-common/focal,now 2.4.107-1029 all [installed]
libdrm-intel1/focal,now 2.4.107-1029 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libdrm-nouveau2/focal,now 2.4.107-1029 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libdrm-radeon1/focal,now 2.4.107-1029 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libdrm2/focal,now 2.4.107-1029 amd64 [installed]
libva-drm2/focal,now 2.13.0+i643~u20.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libva-wayland2/focal,now 2.13.0+i643~u20.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libva-x11-2/focal,now 2.13.0+i643~u20.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libva2/focal,now 2.13.0+i643~u20.04 amd64 [installed,automatic]
manage-distro-upgrade/now 2.1~18.04timbuktu1 all [installed,local]
manage-estar-settings/now 1.2~18.04timbuktu1somerville1 all [installed,local]
ocenaudio/now 3.10.3-1 amd64 [installed,local]
oem-beaver-osp1-varys-meta/now 1 all [installed,local]
oem-fix-eth-realtek-disabletlpr8153/unknown,unknown,now 2ubuntu8 all [installed]
oem-hotkey-osd/now 0.4~18.04timbuktu1 all [installed,local]
oem-release/now 1 all [installed,local]
oem-seventy-percent-brightness/now 1.5 all [installed,local]
oem-somerville-partner-archive-keyring/unknown,unknown,now 1.0.1 all [installed,automatic]
oem-ubuntu-boot-video/now 1 all [installed,local]
quarto/now 0.9.188 amd64 [installed,local]
scangearmp-common/now 2.30.1-1804+2ubuntu4 amd64 [installed,local]
scangearmp-mg6200series/now 2.30.1-1804+2ubuntu4 amd64 [installed,local]
scangearmp2/now 4.30.0-2+1804 amd64 [installed,local]
somerville-meta/unknown,unknown,now 6.5~ubuntu18.04.0 all [installed]
sosreport-oem/now 0.1.5 all [installed,local]
timbuktu-meta/now 2.1~18.04timbuktu12 all [installed,local]
tlp-config/now 4 all [installed,local]
tlp-sensible/now 1.4 all [installed,local]
ubuntu-recovery-grub-hotkey/now 1.2~18.04timbuktu1 all [installed,local]
vivaldi-stable/stable,now 5.2.2623.39-1 amd64 [installed]
```

Comment: I noted mention of `sudo apt upgrade` in your post; but that doesn't install all upgrades, with the command `sudo apt full-upgrade` ensuring all packages are upgraded (it allows for removal of outdated packages that can 'apt upgrade' cannot do thus leaving behind upgrades).  (`apt-get` provided the command `apt-get dist-upgrade` which is the equivalent to `apt full-upgrade`)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, the command `sudo apt full-upgrade` doesn't do anything: `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.` And `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` doesn't either: `Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded`.

Comment: It seems libdrm-amdgpu1/focal is for the Ubuntu 20 but I am on Ubuntu 18. I think this is my problem. I can't upgrade it without breaking things. But I don't (think) I need it because I don't have an AMD GPU, I have an Intel on-chip GPU. But I can't uninstall it without breaking these BIG packages for some reason?

Comment: Specifically, I get from `sudo apt-get remove libdrm-amdgpu1` the following message:```The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt5gui5 : Depends: libgl1 but it is not going to be installed
 phonon4qt5 : Depends: phonon4qt5-backend-vlc but it is not going to be installed or
                       phonon4qt5-backend
 x11-utils : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx but it is not going to be installed or
                      libgl1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```So I'm stuck.

Comment: If I try `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove libgl*` I get the error `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 x11-utils : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx but it is not going to be installed or
                      libgl1 but it is not going to be installed`. But if I try `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove x11-utils` I get `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglx0:i386 : Depends: libglx-mesa0:i386 but it is not going to be installed`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ /etc/apt/sources.list` also `apt-cache policy libdrm-amdgpu1`  I read dell-recovery. Was your system preinstalled?